# How to download a big zip file with curl?

Tags: curl, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to download a big .zip file with curl (from 700mb up to 3gb).

I have tried the following (very basic command):

```
curl -o ul.zip https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/33897a7f-f702-45bc-aacb-410c8179f614
```

The url is the one provided by the french government here: https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/base-sirene-des-entreprises-et-de-leurs-etablissements-siren-siret/

However, I expected a 654.5 MB file, but the output of my curl is this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   335  100   335    0     0   2481      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2481
```

And I get a very small file that contains only this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://files.data.gouv.fr/insee-sirene/StockUniteLegale_utf8.zip">http://files.data.gouv.fr/insee-sirene/StockUniteLegale_utf8.zip</a>.
```

So I tried to use the redirection URL, which gives me the following output from curl:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I download that file with curl ? (knowing that downloading it via web browser works perfectly fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I always need to search for the correct key words AFTER I ask on SE...

If I understood well:

There is a redirection. Curl does not follow it by default, but you can tell curl to do it with the following option:

```
-L
```

Source: https://curl.se/docs/faq.html#301_Moved_Permanently